# Use values from edited table for calculations in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

What I am attempting to do, is to allow the user to pass in a configuration/lookup excel table into shiny, display this table in shiny, allow the user to make cells edits in shiny, and use the values that were edited from the editable table for calculations. My problem arises for the last step "use the values that were edited from the editable table for calculations".

The excel file consists of 2 tabs with data of the following content:

Tab1 Name: "parameters"
data.frame(Name = c("a", "b", "c"), Value = c(1:3))

Tab2 Name: "parameters2"
data.frame(Name = c("a", "b", "c"), Value = c(4:6))

The ideal shiny app would do the following:

1) At upload, perform a calculation adding the unchanged first values of Tab 1 and Tab 2. This would be 1 + 4 = 5.

2) If user edits Tab 1's value of 1 to 8, then the calculation would result in 8 + 4 = 12.

Effectively, I want to use the edited tables values to update all my calculations if the user makes any edits to it. I know this can be done by simply uploading a new file in shiny, but I would rather allow them to do this in shiny as opposed to uploading a new file.

Here is my shiny app. Appreciate any help/guidance!

```
    library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput(inputId = "config", label = "Upload Configuration File", 
              multiple = F, accept = c(".xlsx", ".xls")), 
    verbatimTextOutput("txt"), 
    tagList(tags$head(tags$style(type = 'text/css','.navbar-brand{display:none;}')),
            navbarPage(title = "",
                       tabPanel(title = "Parameters",
                                dataTableOutput(outputId = "edit.param", width = 2)), 
                       tabPanel(title = "Parameters2",
                                dataTableOutput(outputId = "edit.param2", width = 2))
            )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    config.path = reactive({

      inFile = input$config

      if(is.null(inFile)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        return(inFile$datapath)
      }

    })

    df.param = reactive({
      read_excel(path = config.path(), sheet = "parameters")
    })

    df.param2 = reactive({
      read_excel(path = config.path(), sheet = "parameters2")
    })

    output$edit.param = renderDT(df.param(), selection = "none", server = F, editable = "cell")
    output$edit.param2 = renderDT(df.param2(), selection = "none", server = F, editable = "cell")

    observeEvent(input$edit.param_cell_edit, {
      df.param()[input$edit.param_cell_edit$row, input$edit.param_cell_edit$col] <<- input$edit.param_cell_edit$value
    })

    observeEvent(input$edit.param2_cell_edit, {
      df.param()[input$edit.param2_cell_edit$row, input$edit.param2_cell_edit$col] <<- input$edit.param2_cell_edit$value
    })

    output$txt = reactive({

      df.param()$value[1] + df.param2()$value[1]

    })

  }

)
```

I also tried this for the server section and had no luck either:

```
    output$edit.param = renderDT(df.param(), selection = "none", server = F, editable = "cell")
output$edit.param2 = renderDT(df.param2(), selection = "none", server = F, editable = "cell")

observe(input$edit.param_cell_edit)
observe(input$edit.param2_cell_edit)
```

Comment: You should avoid using dots in the ids (such as `edit.param`). But the main problem in you app is `output$txt`, which should be `output$txt = renderPrint({df.param()$value[1] + df.param2()$value[1]})`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent dots are pretty standard in R. Is there an issue in using them in Shiny? I haven't experienced any issues. Good catch on the renderPrint, but that still doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: A dot in Javascript is somehow similar to `$` in R. There's an issue if you use an id with a dot in the Javascript condition of a `conditionalPanel` for example, because, for example if the id is `id.dot`, then `input.id.dot` in Javascript is interpreted as the `dot` element of the `id` element of `input`. What is the problem you get ? Is there an error message ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I don't have any errors or warning messages. My main issue is how to pass on the values for calculations after editing a table in shiny. I know how to make the table editable, but I do not know how to pass those edited values into calculations. For example, I upload a file that has alpha = 1, and my initial calculation would be e^(1) = 2.72. Now, if I edit it in shiny to alpha = 2, my new calculation should be e^(2) =7.39.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this? (I have not tried).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput(inputId = "config", label = "Upload Configuration File", 
              multiple = F, accept = c(".xlsx", ".xls")), 
    verbatimTextOutput("txt"), 
    tagList(tags$head(tags$style(type = 'text/css','.navbar-brand{display:none;}')),
            navbarPage(title = "",
                       tabPanel(title = "Parameters",
                                dataTableOutput(outputId = "edit_param", width = 2)), 
                       tabPanel(title = "Parameters2",
                                dataTableOutput(outputId = "edit_param2", width = 2))
            )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    config.path = reactive({

      inFile = input$config

      if(is.null(inFile)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        return(inFile$datapath)
      }

    })

    df_param <- reactiveVal()
    observe({
      req(config.path())
      df_param(read_excel(path = config.path(), sheet = "parameters"))
    })

    df_param2 <- reactiveVal()
    observe({
      req(config.path())
      df_param2(read_excel(path = config.path(), sheet = "parameters2"))
    })

    output$edit_param = renderDT({
      req(df_param())
      datatable(isolate(df_param()), selection = "none", editable = "cell")
    })
    output$edit_param2 = renderDT({
      req(df_param2())
      datatable(isolate(df_param2()), selection = "none", editable = "cell")
    })

    proxy <- dataTableProxy("edit_param")
    proxy2 <- dataTableProxy("edit_param2")

    observeEvent(input$edit_param_cell_edit, {
      info <- input$edit_param_cell_edit
      df_param(editData(df_param(), info, proxy, resetPaging = FALSE))
    })

    observeEvent(input$edit_param2_cell_edit, {
      info <- input$edit_param2_cell_edit
      df_param2(editData(df_param2(), info, proxy2, resetPaging = FALSE))
    })

    output$txt = renderPrint({
      df_param()$value[1] + df_param2()$value[1]
    })

  }

)
```